# How do i get the sublimetext Autoprefix CSS plugin working on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-2, node.js

I installed everything per this Article: [Adding CSS Vendor Prefix Automatically with Sublime Text](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-automatic-vendor-prefix/)

But when i <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and select `Autoprefix CSS`, while am on a `.CSS` file, nothing happens?

How can i get the sublimetext2 `Autoprefix CSS` plugin to work on Ubuntu 13.10(amd64)?

---

According to the [readme](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer#sublime-autoprefixer) i should install `nodejs` i did like so: sudo apt-get install nodejs.

But when doing `node -v`, I get no output?

---

I finally got something from it:

> Autoprefixer [Errno 32] Broken pipe

And i reported it: [Autoprefixer [Errno 32] Broken pipe · Issue #31 · sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer/issues/31)

---

`$PATH`

```
/home/$USERNAME/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 0):

Change keyboard shortcut settings, go to: `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`.

And add <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut with the `autoprefixer` command:

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+super+p"], "command": "autoprefixer" }
]
```

Comment: Not working. Do i need to save the file in a different file name, like so: `autoprefixer (Linux).sublime-keymap`?

Comment: @blade19899 No! Add to you `.css` file line: `body { transition-delay: 0s; }` then press shortcut `alt+super+p`. For more details see [AutoPrefixer README.md](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer#sublime-autoprefixer).

Comment: `Autoprefixer
[Errno 32] broken pijp`?

Comment: [Autoprefixer \[Errno 32\] Broken pipe · Issue #31 · sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer/issues/31) - now we play the waiting game :/

Comment: @blade19899 I see this error only Sublime Text 2 on similar plugins. I use Sublime 3 and Autoprefixer CSS work for me. Try to install 3 version of Sublime and issues be resolved. Also see the same [issue](http://goo.gl/iU54Hf).

Comment: I tried sublimetext3, but no luck. Also doesn't work. `But when doing node -v, I get no output?` <- could that be the problem?

Comment: @blade19899 Maybe because when I run `node -v` output is: `v0.10.24`. Try to [install Node.js](http://goo.gl/MnKmVy).